# XMLHttpRequest.responseXML fires 'permission denied' exception

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon-sdk, permission-denied

I'm working on a firefox addon which needs support for ajax requests. The requests will all be sent to the 'messagebeam.tagpulse.nl' domain, so I added it to the permissions in package.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "messagebeam",
    "title": "Message Beam for Android™",
    "id": "jid1-j831e5AVhpvjDA",
    "description": "With one click bidirectionally beam anything you want between Chrome and your Android device!",
    "permissions": {
        "cross-domain-content": ["http://messagebeam.tagpulse.nl/"]
    },  
    "author": "TwZ",
    "license": "MPL 2.0",
    "version": "0.3"
}
```

So far so good. In my main.js, I defined a (very basic) widget and a panel (in main.js) to demonstrate the problem:

```
var testPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width:430,
  height:500,
  contentURL: data.url("test.html"),
  contentScriptFile: [
                        data.url('scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js'),
                        data.url('test.js')
                      ]
});
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "test-popup",
  label: "Message Beam",
  contentURL: data.url("img/test.png"),
  panel: testPanel
});
```

The test.html is very basic (no content):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        No content
    </body>
</html>
```

The test.js (the actual code that produces the permission denied error):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            console.log('finished');
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
            console.log('reported xml');
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://messagebeam.tagpulse.nl/test/test2.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
});
```

The xml returned is as follows (with content-type: text/xml response header, test using http://messagebeam.tagpulse.nl/test/test2.php):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<test>
  text
</test>
```

And now the question: why does the `console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML)` line produce the following error:

```
console.log: messagebeam: finished
System JS : ERROR resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///c:/users/js/appdata/local/temp/tmpfcjrsq.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-j831e5AVhpvjDA@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/sandbox.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/content-worker.js:81
                     Error: Permission denied to access property 'toJSON'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's first a good idea to look at the line of code mentioned in the error message. Here it is `resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/content-worker.js`, line 81 - this is Add-on SDK code integrated into the browser. In Firefox 26 this line says:

```
let str = JSON.stringify(args, replacer);
```

This code belongs to the messaging mechanism of content workers. `toJSON` is being [called implicitly by `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) on the objects that are being serialized.

Obviously, accessing `xmlhttp.responseXML` doesn't trigger any content worker events. However, `console.log()` does - right below the problematic `createPipe` method in `content-worker.js` you can see an `injectConsole` method. This one provides `console` API for content workers, and it will use messaging to forward any calls to the main extension code.

At that point the issue should be obvious: even though the "real" `console.log()` method can deal with parameters of type `XMLDocument`, the one provided to content workers cannot - it expects an object that can be serialized to JSON. Calling `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` should work however. Also, `console.log(new XMLSerializer.serializeToString(xmlhttp.responseXML))` might work (I'm not sure whether the [`XMLSerializer` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) is defined in the worker context).

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. This actually makes sense. However, there is one more issue (quite related). I still cannot 'access' responseXML. I've made a new Xml document and parsed the responseText and that worked (i.e. console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].nodeValue); shows 'text', but doing console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML.childNodes[0].nodeValue); still comes up with a permission denied (on childNodes). Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Toverbal: No, not really - sounds like a side-effect of the sandboxes used by the Add-on SDK. Probably worth [filing as an Add-on SDK bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK).

Comment: I will do that. I wonder what they think of it. Thanks again!

Comment: I've made a bug report. You can find it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966609